# build_opener vs. urlopen for self-signed SSL cert

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, urllib2

I'm trying to get the opener in urllib to work with a self-signed SSL cert in Python 2.7.9.  It works perfectly with simple, direct urlopen, like so:

```
import urllib2

req = urllib2.Request('https://myurl.com')
r = urllib2.urlopen(req,cafile='/my/certs.pem')
r.read()
```

... But when I use (what I think is) effectively the same thing setting a handler instead ...

```
import ssl
import urllib2

s = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
s.load_verify_locations(cafile='/my/certs.pem')
sh = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(s)
o = urllib2.build_opener(sh)
r = o.open('https://myurl.com')
r.read()
```

... I get an error on the cert:

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:581)>
```

EDIT: I've simplified my example for the purposes of the question, but I need to use the second version, because I need to add another handler (for digest authentication) before opening the connection.  So, if there's an alternative option for using self-signed certs with digest authentication, I'm all ears!

Been a while since I've been on here ... Thanks in advance for your help.